# Renamed MySQL table not renamed for INSERT queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert, mysql-error-1146

After renaming one of my MySQL 5.1 MyISAM tables from `test_tablename` to `tablename`, I have found that if I try to execute an INSERT (or REPLACE) query, I get the following message:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (...) VALUES (...)
```

> 1146: Table 'dbname.test_tablename' doesn't exist

I have triple-checked my database abstraction code, and verified this by running the query directly on the server.

According to the MySQL server, the `CREATE TABLE` syntax is `tablename`, as expected, and when I run `SHOW TABLES`, it lists `tablename` as expected.

Is there any reason for this to happen?

More importantly, is there an easier way to fix this than dumping, dropping, re-creating, and reloading the table?

Comment: Yesterday I chopped off my left arm, and today I've found that I'm unable to grasp things on my left side. Why is that?

Comment: I assume you mean that you are explicitly inserting into table `tablename`, but the error message is still referencing the old tablename?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've updated the question to clarify the query I am executing.

Comment: Is it possible that you have any trigger on the mentioned table?

Comment: @jweyrich: Yep that was it. If you make that an answer, I'll accept it. I can't believe I missed that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be caused by a trigger that has not been updated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If you renamed `test_tablename` to `tablename`, shouldn't the following be true ?

```
1146: Table 'dbname.test_tablename' doesn't exist
```

Be sure to use `tablename` in your queries, not `test_tablename`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to clarify: my queries reference `tablename`, not `test_tablename`.

Comment: since you're error says test_tablename doesn't exist there must be a view/query refering to it . please double check

Comment: I am not using views, so that's not an issue, and there are no stored queries to worry about. I've ran the query directly on the server, no in-between code to worry about, and I still get the error, and only for INSERT/REPLACE.

Comment: please post the query you tryed to run ( show create table tablename would be usefull too ) .

Comment: Well, the query is the same as my updated question (of course the names are different, and you can put whatever you want in the `...` and it still won't work.), and you definitely don't want to see the whole `create table`, as there are 100-some irrelevant fields, but it looks like `CREATE TABLE tablename ( ... ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not inserting into a view that still references `test_tablename`?